# How to create audio deformation effects in actionsctipt 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, audio-processing

I use NetConnection, NetStream and Video classes to show video in actionscript 3 (AIR SDK 31.0.0.96) and I can play/stop/pause video, but I don't know how can I add any audio effects (speed changing, distortion, waves or something else).
In my game user has to guess video by deformated sound and for some reasons deformated effect should to be applied in runtime.
I hope, that you will can advice me some library for process audio track in runtime or show me simple code example to access to audio from actionscript.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you providing the video files yourself? For less work, you want an FLV container (not MP4) and the audio track should be MP3 (not the usual AAC found in videos). Basically to adjust speed or other effect, you need to edit the bytes holding the PCM samples (uncompressed audio data). AS3 can un-compress MP3 into PCM and give you the bytes to play with before sending to output (speakers).

Comment: No, I'm not providing files myself. My programm it is constructor for other people and I guess that video in most cases will be in mp4 format.